# How to achieve a forward assignment of m2m object in django?

Tags: python, django

I know this is a weird question and also aware that django doesn't allow forward creation of m2m objects. Firstly my `models.py` is:

```py
class Option(models.Model):
     option = m.CharF(...)

class Question(models.Model):
     question = m.CharF(...)
     answer = m.CharF(...)
     option = m.m2m(Option)


class Test(models.Model):
     name = m.CF(...)
     question = m.m2m(Question)
```

As you can see my model, it is a structure for online question paper. I know that only existing questions and options can be added while creating a new test object. How can i achieve my objective of creating the `Test`, `Question` and `Option` objects at the same time.

After searching around stackoverflow and some googling, i came to know about `.add()` but that didn't suite my goal. Any solutions? If you can, please do add a `views.py` for it. That would be of great help.

Comment: How does `add()` not suit your requirements?

Comment: Even `add()` only adds an existing object. Am i wrong?

Comment: You just create the `Option`s first, save them, then create a `Question`, save it, then create the `Test`, save it, and finally `add()` the options and questions to the respective relationship.

Comment: if you want all 3 objects to be created at the same time you need to override the `save()` or `create()` method of one, and in that method, create the other two objects, and make references to eachother using the m2m field on that object

Comment: If you don't mind, can you post it as answer with the correct `views.py`? I would be useful for future references also.